# Why calling a generic method with different types gives compilation error?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to learn java generics. I wrote a method:

```
public <T> T Gmethod(T a,Collection<T> list){   
        return a;}
```

While calling this with `Gmethod("A",list);` is fine where list is type of `Object`,

But calling it with `Gmethod(new Object(),list);`where list is type of `String` is error, 
Why?

Comment: You are trying to pass two different Types, so which Type do you suppose to become parameter of T?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having

```
<T> T method(T a, Collection<T> list) { return a; }
```

and calling it with

```
Collection<Object> list = new LinkedList<>();
method("A", list);
```

will cause the compiler to infer the type `Object` for the type variable `T`, as `list` is of type `Collection<Object>`. The type of variable `a` is `String`, which is a subtype of `Object`. So this method call is allowed.

Calling the method with

```
Collection<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
method(new Object(), list);
```

will again cause the compiler to infer the type Object for the type variable `T`, as now `a` is of type `Object`. So the compiler requests the argument for parameter `list` to be of type `Collection<Object>` (or a subtype). **But `Collection<String>` is not a subtype of `Collection<Object>`.** So the compiler does not allow this method call.

Comment: Absolutely correct by saying this "<...> But Collection<String> is not a subtype of Collection<Object> <...>" . +1

Answer (score 2):

When you have a reference `T` the actual class can be T or a subclass.  When you have a `<T>` it has to be that class and only that class.  This is required as it is a container of a references and modifying this container can alter the original. This doesn't happen with a plain reference as it is passed as a copy.

A reference is copied by value.

```
String a = "hi";
Object b = a;
b = new Object(); // no problem as `a` is not changed by this.
```

But for containers this doesn't work so well as only the reference to the container is copied, not the container itself.

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add("hi");
List<Object> b = (List) a; // compiler warning.
b.add(new Object());       // alters `a` in an incorrect way.
a.get(1);                  // ClassCastException oops.
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: +1 Yes I get it now. I have also provided my perspective of understanding to it. Can you please also go through my answer to validate my understanding. I'll be grateful. Thanks. Every new day I get stumped by generics in some way :(

Answer (score 1):

As @Seelenvirtuose and @Peter Lawrey have suggested in their answer that this is because of Type Inference that compiler does for you.

To test that compiler binds the first call to `Object` try this,

```
class Main{

     public static void main(String[] args){
          Collection<Object> listOfObject = new ArrayList<>();
          Main.<String>method("a",listOfObject); //compile time error here
     }

     public static <T> T Gmethod(T a, Collection<T> coll){
        return a;
     }
}
```

Comment: You said, "a Collection<String> cannot contain an Object". Although that is true, it is not the problem! In fact, the problem is: The compiler requests all arguments to be the same type or a subtype of a method parameter. And it is Collection<String> that is not a subtype of Collection<Object>. The subtype relationship between String and Object does not matter!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose `The compiler requests all arguments to be the same type or a subtype of a method parameter.` is it subtype or supertype? In first case a super type is chosen. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: In both method calls, the compiler infers type Object for T (first, it is because _list_ is of type Collection<Object>, second it is because _a_ is of type Object. So the method's signature - for both calls - is `Object method (Object a, Collection<Object> list)`. Calling this method with actual arguments forces the argument for _a_ to be of type Object or subtype (which could be anything) and it forces the argument for _list_ to be of type Collection<Object> or subtype. But Collection<String> ist not a subtype of Collection<Object>. By the way, List<Object> would be such a subtype.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Thanks alot for putting effort to make me understand. I appreciate it. :)

Comment: Hey, you're welcome. Generics and variance are sometimes very difficult, I know.